# How to compare the difference between 2 videos color in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774996/ , but "blend=all_mode=difference" is green.
How do I get more colorful diffrence using blend filter?

Sample command is

```
ffplay -f lavfi "movie=left.mp4,split[a1][a2]; movie=right.mp4,split[b1][b2]; [a1][b1]blend=all_mode=difference[blend];[a2]pad=2*iw:2*ih[left];[left][b2]overlay=w[tmp];[tmp][blend]overlay=0:h"
```

[image]

using "hue=s=0", color chenges monochrome.

```
ffplay -f lavfi "movie=left.mp4,split[a1][a2]; movie=right.mp4,split[b1][b2]; [a1][b1]blend=all_mode=difference,hue=s=0[blend];[a2]pad=2*iw:2*ih[left];[left][b2]overlay=w[tmp];[tmp][blend]overlay=0:h"
```

[image]

My goal is this video. If you have a niconico account.
http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm24864058

If you don't have a niconico account, embed page is
http://www.nicozon.net/watch/sm24864058

Comment: Do any of the other [blend modes](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blend) provide what you need?

Comment: If that works for you then you can write and accept your own answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2):

When using "c0_mode" instead of "all_mode" is fine.

```
ffplay -f lavfi "movie=left.mp4,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split[a1][a2];
                movie=right.mp4,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split[b1][b2];
                [a1][b1]blend=c0_mode=difference,pad=2*iw:ih:0:0[down];
                [a2][b2]hstack[up];[up][down]vstack"
```

[image]

Anothre way to compare 2 videos.

```
ffplay -f lavfi "movie=left.mp4,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split=3[a0][a1][a2];
                movie=right.mp4,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split[b0][b1];
                [a0][b0]blend=c0_mode=difference[y];
                [a1]lutyuv=y=val:u=128:v=128[uv];
                [y][uv]mergeplanes=0x001112:yuv420p,pad=2*iw:ih:0:0[down];
                [a2][b1]hstack[up];[up][down]vstack"
```

Comment: Adding three screenshots.